# Different version of Facebook iOS SDK and Audience Network iOS SDK in the same app

Tags: facebook-ios-sdk

Since the introduction of of the Facebook Audience Network SDK for iOS, Facebook started to release updates to the two SDKs together. I was wondering... can we use different versions of the SDKs in the same app or there are dependencies that require both to be included and from the same version?

The reason of the question is that they recently dropped support for iOS 5 in the main Facebook SDK while such thing didn't happen on the Audience Network SDK. Therefore I'd like to integrate a *pre-drop* version of the Facebook SDK together with the latest Audience Network SDK.

Is this possible?

I went through the documentation but I haven't seen anything mentioning this scenario...

Answer (score 1):

The answer is "YES", it can be done. The two SDKs are independent from each other...